# Difference between two expressions in C

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I am currently working on an issue in legacy code fully developed in C. It uses shared memory concept. I want to understand some of the expressions used in that.
Assume a struct

```
> typedef struct
> {
>     void* base;
>     ....
> }shm_test_t;
```

The expression is like this,

```
> shm_test_t test;
> test.base = (void*)(unsigned8*)&test;
> unsigned8* l_base = (unsigned8*)test.base;
> unsigned8* s_base = (unsigned8*)&(test.base);
```

and then,they did this

```
unsigned8 l_diff = l_base - s_base;
unsigend8 s_diff = s_base - l_base;
```

I can't understand why they are subtracting two pointers. Won't it return the same value(zero)? Is it related to Linux IPC? This is really confusing. Please help

Comment: `test.base = &test;` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't understand why they are subtracting two pointers. Won't it return the same value(zero)?

Yes, but only if the `base` member is the first one in the structure. `l_base` is the address of the structure, whereas `s_base` is the address of the `base` member in that structure, both converted to pointers to `unsigned8`.

C99 and later does say explicitly that if `base` is the first member in the structure, it has the same address as the structure.

> Is it related to Linux IPC?

No, not that I can see.

---

There is a vaguely similar pattern that is related to shared memory interprocess communication, however.

Let's say you have a `struct shared_data *shared`, that points to shared memory.

Because each process has their own virtual address space, although the *contents* of `shared` are shared, each process can have it at a different address, i.e. the value of `shared` itself can vary.

This means that using pointers inside shared memory is basically useless. Just because a specific pointer value in one process points to a specific part of the shared memory, does not mean it does so in all processes.

Instead of pointers, you need to store *offsets* relative to `shared`, so that `0` refers to the first address in the shared memory region, and so on. (Or some other similar scheme relative to the beginning of the shared memory.)

To do so, you might see code similar to

```
intptr_t  shared_offset = (intptr_t)shared;
```

The type `intptr_t` is the portable POSIX-compatible type. In Linux, you can use `long`.  The problem is, there exists old code that uses `int`, and even old books that use `int` there in their examples, but it won't work correctly on 64-bit architectures like newer Intel and AMD computers, for example.

Anyway, to convert a byte offset at say `shared[5].next` to a pointer to `footype`, say `footype *foo`, you need to use either

```
foo = (footype *)((char *)shared + shared[5].next);
```

or

```
foo = (footype *)(shared_offset + shared[5].next);
```

Both are equivalent; the former uses the `shared` pointer directly, and the latter uses the `shared_offset` variable.

The inverse conversion, from `foo` to an offset, is e.g.

```
offset =  (ptrdiff_t)((char *)foo - (char *)shared);
```

or

```
offset = (intptr_t)foo - shared_offset;
```

This approach is fragile in the sense that it takes a lot of care to write all those expressions correctly, while ensuring the underlying logic is also correct. (I think of it as similar to trying to tap with one hand, and draw a circle with the other, simultaneously. Most people need a lot of practice to do it right.)

If at all possible, it is better to use an array, and array indexing, instead of offsets to the beginning to the shared memory.

I've only seen this offsetting method used sensibly when the size of each element varied. Even then, there are usually better algorithmic approaches.

Comment: Re “C99 and later does say explicitly that if base is the first member in the structure, it has the same address as the structure.” C 1999 does not say that explicitly. The C standard uses abstractions to discuss pointers and addresses, and two pointers of incompatible types can never be compared—at least one must be converted first. The standard says that a pointer to the initial member of a structure when “suitably converted” points to the structure and vice-versa. That conversion could manipulate the pointer in ways not specified by the standard.